# Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module" - GTK error in VMware

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, gtk

am using ubuntu 14.4. now when i try to install VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle i got error,

```
Extracting VMware Installer...done. Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar": liboverlay-scrollbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module": libunity-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory No protocol specified No protocol specified
```

-> after this gui fail to load for installation procedure, so only can do installation via terminal. But after installation it won't run.

how i can run vmware? What i need to install?